# how to valid only digit in textbox in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have problem to valid digit in textbox in IE 9 and firefox 4 & 5,
is any one know ?
i try all previous question's answer but still face problem,
i just want use to enter only digit in textbox,
i am use asp.net too for code language.

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Comment: i know but that code is not working in IE 9 and Firefox 4 & 5

Comment: @Bhargav Which code? There are several solutions there. Closing as duplicate.

Comment: i used all the code but no one working in firefox 4 & 5

Comment: if code not work its not right solution

Comment: window.event is not working in firefox 4 & 5

Comment: @Bhargav I tested [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input/469419#469419) and it works fine in IE9 and FF5: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfyVc/1/). The problem might be PEBKAC. Btw, I wrote a simple jQuery solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've understood you want to allow only numeric characters in the text field and you will return other characters if they are not numeric. So, you may go through this

step1. create a javascript function

```
<script language="text/javascript">
function onlyNumbers(evt)
{
var e = window.event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

return true;

}
</script>
```

step2. onkeypress call the function like this

If you call any javascript method on any event the first parameter always passed is event. For IE you need to catch the event by window.event.

For more clear ideas you can visit:- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event

Answer (score 0):

Try the [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea onkeyup="test(this);"></textarea>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(el) {
el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
}
</script>
```

Comment: That will allow a fullstop - that is not what the user wants. 
use /[^0-9]/g.

Comment: i already use this code but my TL said me they don't want any thing to show in textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="vldNumber" ControlToValidate="txtNumber" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Numeric Value" ValidationExpression="(^([0-9]*|\d*\d{1}?\d*)$)" Runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, it is quite easy to implement.

You should mark your inputs that need to be numeric only with a class (inline event handlers are mostly useless if you have jQuery anyways):

```
<input type="text" class="numericInput">
```

and use this little jQuery:

```
$('input.numericInput').keypress(function (e) {
    return /[0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

Tested: Chrome, FF4, IE9. If you want to allow other characters, just manipulate the regex. You might want to allow some other keys, like Backspace.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfyVc/)

Comment: @Bhargav Then how come it works? I promise I'm not a magician. [Firefox supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/event.which), just like IE9, but jQuery normalizes `event.which` anyways, so it will work.